# PHP / JSON charset decoding

Tags: php

I am reading JSON data in PHP with data sent from an Android handphone. The user submits a name and the JSON/PHP stuffs it into a MySql db.  Some of my users are Korean. Android handles   the Korean characters just fine, but when the data comes over via JSON and then read in the PHP like so:

```
$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
$data = json_decode($json);

$username = $data->username;
```

A perfectly good Korean syllable such as "김" is mutated into $username as "9C9G". In my Eclipse debugger, I can see the name is still formatted correctly on the Android side but the PHP side is not. I haven't even gotten to the MySQL stage yet and it's already jacked.

What should be doing on the PHP side to accept other characters? I merely want to stuff the name into a table and refer to it later in a string. Also, what will I need to do to when stuff the MySQL db with these chars?

It is sent from an Android app like so:

```
   public void postData() throws JSONException{ 
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://martypants.us/triominoes/register.php");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

try {
   JSONArray postjson = new JSONArray();
   postjson.put(json);

   // Post the data:
   httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
   httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);

   // Execute HTTP Post Request
   System.out.print(json);
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 <snip>
 }
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($json)` give you, i.e. how is the data sent from the client in the first place?

Comment: Well, that's weird since `json_decode()` would return `NULL` if the string isn't encoded correctly, so the problem could be in the database? Do your MySQL table and column (where you store the username) have the correct encoding (utf8_general_ci, usually)?

Comment: var_dump just gives me some scrambled characters like "@�l" - and I'm not even stuff the db at this point. I

Comment: just added details above on how the json is sent from Android to PHP

Comment: Why are you sending the JSON content entirely in the header instead of the body? What encoding or format is Android's `json.toString` encoding the string in? Please show a `bin2hex($json)` and/or the complete JSON string, if you're getting gobbledegook with a `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said about *"Android handles the Korean characters just fine"* I can only infer that Android is passing data into your PHP app as UTF8 and you are not properly decoding it. My guess is you to attempt something like this:

```
//this is reaaaaally not safe, but... missing the point 
$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];

//check if it's utf8 
if ( is_string($value) ){
    $json = mb_check_encoding($json, 'UTF-8') ? utf8_encode( $json ) : $json; 
}

$jsonData = json_decode($json);
```

It's just a thought, but when using PHP, encodings have made my life miserable more than once.

Hope I can help!

Comment: "encodings have made my life miserable more than once" - Not meaning to be rude, but that's probably because you don't understand encodings or how PHP (not) handles them. The use of `utf8_encode` is something of an indicator. Using it you'll never be able to display any Korean characters, since it converts *from Latin1*, which cannot encode Korean characters. May I recommend [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: No need to say "Not meaning to be rude", I always take clarification from other devs as a good thing, it hurted my pride long ago, but then I realized that only mediocre people can't handle critic and spot on with encodings and PHP, after all, I'm a .net guy :)

Comment: ok, so if I understand things correctly, Android defaults to UTF-8 so that's what it should have been sending since I made no other parameters changes.  But if it's correctly encoded such that I can read on my desktop and on my phone in Korean then why is my PHP not able to?    utf8_encode does not work, as it expects iso-8991 or such.  I've run mb_internal_encoding and it seems to think it has utf16, but that doesn't do anything for getting legible results

Comment: @Martin, you are quite close to get it, my proposal, is that you use the mb_check_encoding or similar to get the encoding of the request you are getting and try to convert it from there...